# How do we conclude that $[m_1, m_2] \mid a-b$??

Tags: number-theory

> $(m_1,m_2)=1, a \equiv b \pmod {m_1} , a \equiv b \pmod {m_2} \Leftrightarrow a \equiv b \pmod {m_1 \cdot m_2}$

The proof of the direction $" \Rightarrow "$ is the following:

$a \equiv b \pmod {m_1} , a \equiv b \pmod {m_2}$

Then $m_1 \mid a-b, m_2 \mid a-b$

So $[m_1, m_2] \mid a-b$

But $[m_1, m_2]=\frac{m_1 \cdot m_2}{(m_1, m_2)}=m_1 \cdot m_2$

So $m_1 \cdot m_2 \mid a-b$, so $a \equiv b \pmod {m_1 \cdot m_2}$

$$$$
Could you explain me how we conclude from $"m_1 \mid a-b, m_2 \mid a-b "$ that $"[m_1, m_2] \mid a-b"$??

Comment: $m,n\mid c\,\Rightarrow\, {\rm lcm}(m,n)\mid c,\ $ e.g. [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/727625/242)

Comment: You might also skip a couple of steps. Since $(m_1,m_2)=1$, all prime factors in $m_1$ are *not* in $m_2$ and vice versa. Since all those prime factors *are* in $a-b$, it follows that $m_1 \cdot m_2 | a-b$.

Comment: I got it...Thank you very much!!! :-)